# Application not responding status when the orientation is changed from the portrait to landscape

Tags: android

In MY application the activity is entering in to the **application not responding** state when the `configuration` is changed from the `portrait` to `landscape`

and coming to the piece of the code for the configuration change is:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);        
    mWordSelCategory =mWordCategory;
    Log.d(TAG,"THE CATEGORY IS :: "+mWordSelCategory);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.word_start);
        mImagebackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImgWord_ImageBg);
        if (mWordSelCategory.equals("Animals")) {

            mImagebackground
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.word_start_animals);

        } else if (mWordSelCategory.equals("Fruits")) {

            mImagebackground
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.word_start_fruits);

        } else if (mWordSelCategory.equals("Things")) {

            mImagebackground
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.word_start_objects);

        } else if (mWordSelCategory.equals("Vegetables")) {

            mImagebackground
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.word_start_vegetables);

        }
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.word_start_horizt);
        mImagebackground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImgWord_ImageBg);
        if (mWordSelCategory.equals("Animals")) {

            mImagebackground
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.word_start_hori_animals);

        } else if (mWordSelCategory.equals("Fruits")) {

            mImagebackground
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.word_start_horiz_fruits);

        } else if (mWordSelCategory.equals("Things")) {

            mImagebackground
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.word_start_hori_objects);

        } else if (mWordSelCategory.equals("Vegetables")) {

            mImagebackground
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.word_start_hori_vegetable);
        }

    }

    getReconfigData();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa, you got a lot of code duplication in there.

Refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html and specifically check out the **Providing Alternative Resources** section - you can have the layout system use different layouts depending on whether your device is in landscape or portrait mode automatically.

E.g.

```
res/layout/word_start.xml
res/layout-land/word_start.xml
```

Then you will only have a single call to `setContentView` and all the `findViewById`s ....

Comment: this means i have to use the same xml for both the orientations ,but i want to use different xmls for different orientations

Comment: and more over if we declare them as in a different folder as u told how to call them in the activity

Comment: i did the same thing as u told but the application is still entering in to the ANR state still while pressing on any buttons in the application plz help....

Comment: No it doesnt mean using the same XML. You can have different XML layouts, they just share the same *name*. If you're going to refer to the same elements than the IDs will have to be the same. But you're free to use different styles, etc. Maybe the landscape one is not as tall vertically as the portrait one (the exact scenario I have used this approach for).